# JMS serializer. Xml tag name for array of objects

Tags: php, rest, symfony, jmsserializerbundle

I have some troubles getting the xml output I expect using jms serializer and symfony 3.

I have an entity called "reference". 
Using the annotation @XmlRoot("reference") and returning one object only, the xml output of fos rest bundle is as expected:

```
<reference>
  <id>1</id>
  <title>Title 1</title>
</reference>
```

But if I output an array of the same objects (returned by doctrines `findAll()` method) I get this:

```
<result>
  <entry>
    <id>1</id>
    <title>Title 1</title>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <id>2</id>
    <title>Title 2</title>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <id>3/id>
    <title>Title 3</title>
  </entry>
</result>
```

The tag is called `<entry>` but I'd like to achieve this:

```
<result>
      <reference>
        <id>1</id>
        <title>Title 1</title>
      </reference>
      <reference>
        <id>2</id>
        <title>Title 2</title>
      </reference>
      <reference>
        <id>3/id>
        <title>Title 3</title>
      </reference>
 </result>
```

(I don't know how to use `@XmlList` in this case, because I do not have a parent entity holding the reference items...)

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all your expected XML is not well formatted to me. The `id` should be an atribute instead. The example below does it. See the result at the bottom. If you want more examples then check links below which would teach you a lot.

- [Validating, serialising and mapping XML request to model classes](http://www.inanzzz.com/index.php/post/oxlj/validating-serialising-and-mapping-xml-request-to-model-classes)
- [Validating, serialising and mapping json and XML requests to model classes](http://www.inanzzz.com/index.php/post/6uz7/validating-serialising-and-mapping-json-and-xml-requests-to-model-classes)

**Result**

```
namespace Application/YourBundle/Model;

use Application/YourBundle/Model/Reference;
use JMS\Serializer\Annotation as Serializer;

/**
 * @Serializer\XmlRoot("result")
 */
class Result
{
    /**
     * @var Reference[]
     *
     * @Assert\Valid(traverse="true")
     *
     * @Serializer\XmlList(inline=false, entry="reference")
     * @Serializer\Type("array<Application\YourBundle\Model\Reference>")
     */
    public $references = [];
}
```

**Reference**

```
namespace Application/YourBundle/Model;

use JMS\Serializer\Annotation as Serializer;

class Reference
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @Serializer\Type("integer")
     * @Serializer\XmlAttribute
     */
    public $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @Serializer\Type("string")
     * @Serializer\XmlValue
     */
    public $title;
}
```

This setup should give you:

```
<result>
   <references>
      <reference id="1">Title 1</reference>
      <reference id="2">Title 2</reference>
      <reference id="3">Title 3</reference>
   </references>
</result>
```

If your response was a json object then it would be like this:

```
{
    "references": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "title": "Title 1"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "value": "Title 2"
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "value": "Title 3"
        }
    ]
}
```